# How to not count the date before due date in library fines using php

Tags: php

This is my code of library fines calculation

```
$currentdate= date('Y/m/d');

$start = new DateTime($returndate=$row['due_date']); <-- from database
$end = new DateTime($currentdate);
$days= $start->diff($end, true)->days;
$fines = $days > 0 ? intval(floor($days)) * ₱10 : 0;
```

I want to calculate borrowing books every day after due date cost ₱10 but it just counted the day and display like   [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQaIx.png)  sorry I'm beginner in php coding thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$end` is currentday and because of that it will calculate a fine even if currentdate is less than duedate.
What you need is a if currentday is more than duedate, then calculate the fine.

```
$currentdate = date('Y/m/d');
$start = new DateTime($returndate=$row['due_date']); <-- from database
$end = new DateTime($currentdate);

if(strtotime($currentdate) > strtotime($returndate)){
    $days= $start->diff($end, true)->days;
    $fines = $days > 0 ? intval(floor($days)) * 10 : 0;
}
```

strtotime() will convert a date in string format to UNIX time (integer).

You can test the code here: https://3v4l.org/fl3IM

Edit:

Method 1.

```
$currentdate = date('Y/m/d');
$start = new DateTime($returndate=$row['due_date']); <-- from database
$end = new DateTime($currentdate);

$fines = 0;
if(strtotime($currentdate) > strtotime($returndate)){
    $days= $start->diff($end, true)->days;
    $fines = $days > 0 ? intval(floor($days)) * 10 : 0;
}
```

Now it will show a fine of 0 until someone has passed due date. (may look cluttered in the page)

---

Method 2.

```
$currentdate = date('Y/m/d');
$start = new DateTime($returndate=$row['due_date']); <-- from database
$end = new DateTime($currentdate);

if(strtotime($currentdate) > strtotime($returndate)){
    $days= $start->diff($end, true)->days;
    $fines = $days > 0 ? intval(floor($days)) * 10 : 0;
}

//some other code I guess...  

if(isset($fines)) echo $fines;
```

Here $fines is not set and will not be echoed unless someone is passed due date. This method probably will look the best on the page.
But I don't know exactly how your page is set up.

Comment: Thanks!!! it counted but if I put same day or before due date it gives error http://imgur.com/a/iPoU2

Comment: @KyousukeKousaka Yes that is because the $fines has not been calculated. Either you first find out if it's set and only echo if set, or you set it to 0 and only change if there is a fine. I will update to show you the two methods.

Comment: @KyousukeKousaka no problem. Keep in mind I had to remove your "P" symbol. It didn't work to have that in the code when doing math (at least for me). So either add it in the `echo  "P" . $fines;` or put it back in the math if it worked for you in the past.